# Java inheritance using spring annotation to create bean

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, annotations

We have a concrete class's A and B and we cannot change class B.

1.Class B has 2 private variables var1 and var 2 (Project P1)

2.Class A extends b, and has no variables of its own (Project P2)

Question.
With spring annotation how can we create bean of class B.

```
 public class B
{  private Object var1;
   private Object var2;

  @Required
  public setVar1(final Object var1){.....};
  protected getVar1(final Object var1){.......};

  @Required
  public setVar2(final Object var2){.....};
  protected getVar2(final Object var2){.......};
}

@Component
Public Class A extends B{....}
```

While server startup 
BeanInitializationException: Properties 'var1' and 'var2' are required for bean 'A'

What could be the possible implementation?

Comment: I.e. you want to know how to supply `var1` and `var2` during bean creation? Are they actually of type `Object`? Can you change the `@Required` annotation?